# Refactoring condition with a range of values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, if-statement, switch-statement, refactoring

How might one refactor this bit of Ruby on Rails code?

```
    def select_plan
        unless params[:plan] && (params[:plan] == '1' || params[:plan] == '2' || params[:plan] == '3' || params[:plan] == '4' || params[:plan] == '5' || params[:plan] == '6' || params[:plan] == '7' || params[:plan] == '8')
            flash[:notice] = "Please select a membership plan to register."
            redirect_to root_url
        end
    end
```

Comment: Where do the valid plan numbers come from? Do they come from a database? Is there a constant that defines them somewhere? Are they magic numbers sprinkled throughout the code?

Comment: I ask because having the "6 is a valid plan" fact sitting only in a controller method or in several different places is what you need to refactor, not the cumbersome implementation you have in `select_plan`. Fix the underlying problem and `select_plan` will clean itself up as a side effect.

Comment: @muistooshort - Please excuse my level of experience. The valid plan numbers are present in the database. I am interested in what you have to say. I am not entirely sure of that you mean though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the plan numbers are in the database and there is a `Plan` model then you could simply say something like:

```
@plan = Plan.find_by(:id => params[:plan])
if(!@plan)
  flash[:notice] = "Please select a membership plan to register."
  redirect_to root_url
end
```

Now you have access to the full plan details for the next view so that you can show them the name, description, price, ... and the existence of a plan is stored in only one place (i.e. the database). If you don't need `@plan` then you could say:

```
if(!Plan.where(:id => params[:plan]).exists?)
  ...
end
```

The important point is that there should be exactly one thing that knows what the valid plans are and any time you need to know about plans, you ask that one thing and only that one thing.

The view that ends up calling `select_plan` would also use the database (instead of the literal numbers one through eight) to get the valid plans:

```
<% Plan.order(...).each do |p| %>
  whatever you need to display the plan as an option...
<% end %>
```

Add a new plan to the database and everything still works. Remove/disable a plan and everything still works. Your software will be easier to maintain, have fewer bugs, be easier to understand, and you'll have gained a new good habit rather than a bad one.

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to explain & provide examples of proper RoR. I have implemented the first solution.

Answer (score 3):

I would do something like this.

```
def select_plan
  unless params[:plan].in?('1'..'8')
    flash[:notice] = "Please select a membership plan to register."
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

Or like *mu is too short* suggested: Make `Plan` a real thing. It might be a database model or just a small Ruby Class:

```
# in app/models/plan.rb
require 'set'
class Plan
  VALID_PLANS = Set.new('1'..'8').freeze

  def self.valid_plan?(plan)
    VALID_PLANS.include?(plan)
  end
end

# used like
def select_plan
  unless Plan.valid_plan?(params[:plan])
    flash[:notice] = "Please select a membership plan to register."
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

Comment: I think you're missing the real problem here. "How do I rewrite this `if` statement" is the surface problem, the real problem is "how do I know if `params[:plan]` is a valid plan".

Comment: @muistooshort, I don't understand. It seems to me this does both.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: Presumably a "plan" is a fundamental part of the application so having the available plan numbers as a couple of magic numbers off in a controller method strikes me as a really bad idea. There should be some sort of `Plan` model that knows what the valid plan numbers are, then the controller would just ask `Plan` if `params[:plan]` was valid and `Plan` would probably consult a database. The code as an isolated piece is fine but it smells bad in the context of the application as a whole.